# Get Text from Span returns empty string

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm trying to get the text from the span inside this div with python and selenium:

```
<div class="product-name">
    <span class="h1" itemprop="name">TEXT</span>
</div>
```

I've tried this, however, this returns an empty string:

```
line = dr.find_element_by_class_name('product-name').find_element_by_xpath('.//span').text
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you could simplify the search like this: `line = dr.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="product-name"]/span').text`. If it still doesn't work, it may be a synchronization issue (wait for element instead of searching for it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try using `css_selector` to find desire element in one find statement as below :-

```
line = dr.find_element_by_css_selector('div.product-name > span').text
```

If you're still getting empty string try using `get_attribute("textContent")` as :-

```
line = dr.find_element_by_css_selector('div.product-name > span').get_attribute("textContent")
```

Or using `get_attribute("innerHTML")` as :-

```
line = dr.find_element_by_css_selector('div.product-name > span').get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

**Note** :- You can also use above operation to getting innerText on parent `<div>` element using `class_name` if there is only desire text as :-

```
line = dr.find_element_by_class_name('product-name').text
```

Or

```
line = dr.find_element_by_class_name('product-name').get_attribute("textContent")
```

Comment: Yes, I've used css selector and it works, but I'm just curious to see why my approach does not work.

Comment: It's hard to say why your approach is not working, your approach also is absolutely correct, I think there are more element with same class name and it's locating other span instead of desire. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I find bs4 more intuitive, prehaps this would suite better?

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4


def main():
    html = """<div class="product-name">
            <span class="h1" itemprop="name">TEXT</span>
            </div>"""
    soup = bs4(html, "html.parser")
    print(soup.find_all('div', {"class": "product-name"}))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Concerning your code..

```
line = dr.find_element_by_class_name('product-name').find_element_by_xpath('.//span').text
```

Maybe supposed to be something more inline with:

```
line = dr.find_element_by_classname('product-name')
```

Might remember wrong.