# Find Elements Between Div With Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following HTML code, I want to extract Years and names, I tried everything with no success :

```
<div class="Year">

<span class="date">2019</span>

</div>



<div class="cl2">
    <span class="name">name1</span>
</div>
<div class="cl2">
    <span class="name">name2</span>
</div>
<div class="cl2">
    <span class="name">name3</span>
</div>
<div class="cl2">
    <span class="name">name4</span>
</div>



<div class="Year">
    <span class="date">2020</span>
</div>

<div class="cl2">
    <span class="name">name5</span>
</div>
<div class="cl2">
    <span class="name">name6</span>
</div>
```

What I want to get is :

```
2019
name1
name2
name3
name4
2020
name5
name6
```

I tried the following, using xpath

```
years = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='year']")

for year in years:
    
    print(year.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='date']").text)

names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='name']")

for name in names:
    print(name.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='name']").text)
```

I got :

2019

2020

name1

name2

name3

name4

name5

name6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and `preceding`:

```
names = dict()
for e in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('name'):
    name = e.text
    year = e.find_element_by_xpath("(./preceding::span[@class='date'])[last()]").text
    names[name] = year
```

> {'name1': '2019', 'name2': '2019', 'name3': '2019', 'name4': '2019',
> 'name5': '2020', 'name6': '2020'}

Also you can get all elements and collect using `class`:

```
names = dict()
year = None
for e in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.date, .name'):
    if 'name' in e.get_attribute('class'):
        names[e.text] = year
    if 'date' in e.get_attribute('class'):
        year = e.text
```

> {'name1': '2019', 'name2': '2019', 'name3': '2019', 'name4': '2019',
> 'name5': '2020', 'name6': '2020'}

Comment: Hello Sers , I posted another problem on this same question , Would you please take a look at it if you don't mind 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63215107/following-siblings-selenium-python-with-conditions

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to work with a html file converted to a text file rather than working with the html file directly. This approach gives much more flexibility to extract the desired text from the given source file.

Firstly, import the `import re` library which will allow us to easily parse our html_text file

Then read in the text file and use `.split()` to split the text into a list based off of the year class. Next, iterate over the list and use `re.search` and `re.findall` to target your date and name classes within the text strings.

```
import re 

f = open("html_text.txt", "r")
html_text = (f.read())

text_list = text.split('<div class="Year">')

for year in text_list[1:]:
  date = re.search('<span class="date">(.+?)</span>', year)
  names = re.findall('<span class="name">(.+?)</span>', year)

  print(date.group(1))
  for name in names:
    print(name)
```

The output when printing out the results should look something like this

**Output:**

```
2019
name1
name2
name3
name4
2020
name5
name6
```

Hope this helped!!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find elements between div using `.get_attribute("textContent")` instead of `.text` using tip from [Get Text from Span returns empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937692/get-text-from-span-returns-empty-string)