# following siblings selenium python with conditions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to collect following siblings until a certain sibling, But I still can't figure out how to do it, I tried to locate before and after sibling with class name but I got wrong results

My html is :

```
<div class="MainClass">

        <div class="InfoClass">
            <div class="left-wrap">
              <span class="date">2 August 2020</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="DataClass">
            <em class="Code">
                <span>1</span>
            </em>
        </div>
        
        <div class="DataClass">
            <em class="Code">
                <span>2</span>
            </em>
        </div>
        
        <div class="DataClass">
            <em class="Code">
                <span>3</span>
            </em>
        </div>
        
        <div class="DataClass">
            <em class="Code">
                <span>4</span>
            </em>
        </div>
    
        <div class="InfoClass">
            <div class="left-wrap">
              <span class="date">15 August 2020</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="DataClass">
            <em class="Code">
                <span>5</span>
            </em>
        </div>

        <div class="DataClass">
            <em class="Code">
                <span>6</span>
            </em>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Python Code :

```
mainClass = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='MainClass']//following-sibling::div[@class='InfoClass']")

        for mc in mainClass:
            kDate = header.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='date']").text
            print(kDate)
            
            datarows = header.find_elements_by_xpath("following-sibling::div[@class='DataClass' and preceding-sibling::div[@class='DataClass']]")
            
            for datarow in datarows:
                mc = datarow.find_element_by_xpath(".//em[@class='Code']").text
                print("Code : "+mc)
```

The Results I got:

```
2 August 2020
2
3
4
5
6
15 August 2020 
5
6
```

What I want as a result is this , class "Code" grouped by dates :

```
2 August 2020
1
2
3
4
15 August 2020 
5
6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use same simple code as for previous question but using `list` to collect correct values if `.Code` is not unique. It work also if **2 August 2020** and **15 August 2020** will same `code`

```
codes = list()
for e in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Code'):
    code = e.text
    date = e.find_element_by_xpath("(./preceding::span[@class='date'])[last()]").text
    codes.append({"date": date, "code": code})

for c in codes:
    print(f'date: {c["date"]}, code: {c["code"]}')
```

The output:

```
date: 2 August 2020, code: 1
date: 2 August 2020, code: 2
date: 2 August 2020, code: 3
date: 2 August 2020, code: 4
date: 15 August 2020, code: 5
date: 15 August 2020, code: 6
```

If you want dict with date as a key and codes as values:

```
codes = dict()
for e in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Code'):
    code = e.text
    date = e.find_element_by_xpath("(./preceding::span[@class='date'])[last()]").text
    if date in codes:
        codes[date].append(code)
    else:
        codes.update({date: [code]})

for k, v in codes.items():
    print(f'{k} : {v}')
```

With output:

```
2 August 2020 : ['1', '2', '3', '4']
15 August 2020 : ['5', '6']
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your expected output, why don't you extract the text from all span elements since they are already in order ? For example, with LXML :

```
data=tree.xpath("//span/text()")
print(*data, sep="\n")
```

Output :

```
2 August 2020
1
2
3
4
15 August 2020
5
6
```

If you really want to use loops and create a dictionnary, here's a proposal. First, the data :

```
data = """<div class="MainClass">

        <div class="InfoClass">
            <div class="left-wrap">
              <span class="date">2 August 2020</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="DataClass">
            <em class="Code">
                <span>1</span>
            </em>
        </div>
        
        <div class="DataClass">
            <em class="Code">
                <span>2</span>
            </em>
        </div>
        
        <div class="DataClass">
            <em class="Code">
                <span>3</span>
            </em>
        </div>
        
        <div class="DataClass">
            <em class="Code">
                <span>4</span>
            </em>
        </div>
    
        <div class="InfoClass">
            <div class="left-wrap">
              <span class="date">15 August 2020</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="DataClass">
            <em class="Code">
                <span>5</span>
            </em>
        </div>

        <div class="DataClass">
            <em class="Code">
                <span>6</span>
            </em>
        </div>
</div>"""
```

Then, the code :

```
import lxml.html
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data)

dates = [el.text for el in tree.xpath("//span[@class='date']")]
print(dates)

dc=[]
for els in dates:
    lists=[el.text for el in tree.xpath("//div[span[text()='"+els+"']]/../following-sibling::div[@class='DataClass']//span[preceding::span[@class='date'][1][.='"+els+"']]")]
    dc.append(lists)

print(dc)

dictionary = dict(zip(dates,dc))
print(dictionary)
```

Comments :

First, you extract the dates in a list. Then, all rely upon the following **XPath** (the one you were looking for ?)  to get the corresponding dataclasses :

```
//div[span[text()='"+els+"']]/../following-sibling::div[@class='DataClass']//span[preceding::span[@class='date'][1][.='"+els+"']]
```

`+els+` are the dates previously fetched.

Finally, you construct the dictionnary. This code is written for `LXML`. Just replace the `tree.xpath` with the Selenium equialent(`driver.find_elements_by_xpath`) to make it work.

Output (dates, dataclasses, dictionnary) :

```
['2 August 2020', '15 August 2020']
[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
{'2 August 2020': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], '15 August 2020': ['5', '6']}
```

EDIT : If you need to print the dictionnary, you can use :

```
for keys,values in dictionary.items():
    print(keys)
    print(*values,sep='\n')
```

Output as requested :

```
2 August 2020
1
2
3
4
15 August 2020
5
6
```

Comment: I will test it out and check

Answer (score 1):

As all the divs containing date and data are at same level under MainClass div. We can get desired result uisng one generic xpaths for all spans containing date and data.

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://bilalzamel.htmlsave.net/")

mainClass = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='MainClass']//span")
for mc in mainClass:
    kDate = mc.text
    print(kDate)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @swaroop Humane. As i needed to replace xpath section in datarow with datarowXpath.

Comment: It did not work , I had to change driver to mc in your code, also this is the result I've got : 

2 August 2020
15 August 2020.
If you want ,. here is an html site to test the same html code :

https://bilalzamel.htmlsave.net/

Comment: @dxtr Thanks for sharing html. As i missed one div[@class=left-wrap] between span containing date and sibling div containing data. Also after seeing HTML, as all the divs are on same level under main class, it is not a possible to group them based on sibling notation. However solution is very simple to get your desired result. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way that will display the text you want it.

```
mainClassText = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='MainClass']").text
print(mainClassText)
```

if you want you can also turn this into list.

```
mainClassTextList = mainClassText.split("\n")
for ele in mainClassTextList:
    print(ele)
```

It will be displayed in both cases:

```
2 August 2020
1
2
3
4
15 August 2020
5
6
```

Comment: Thanks , but that's not what I want , I want to loop elements because there are other data I need to collect